How can I rebalance splits after the window size of the terminal changed?
I sometimes like using splits. Both vertical and horizontal, depending on the files I'm looking at. When creating a split, vim automatically halves the available size of, in my case, a terminal emulator like mate-terminal.
However, if I change the window size of that terminal, vim keeps the size of each split as it was, which I agree is a sensible default. I'm looking for a command to force vim to redistribute the available size anew as if I had opened a new split. Looking at :help split I only see various ways to open a new split, not to rearrange existing ones.

You are using windows, not "splits", therefore :help split is irrelevant.
The closest to a "rearrange all existing windows" command would be :help ctrl-w_=, which is the first listed under :help window-resize.
You can tell Vim to execute that command when the terminal window (CLI Vim) or the GUI window (GVim) is resized with the following autocommand:
augroup AutomaticStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimResized * wincmd =
augroup END

See :help autocommands and :help :wincmd.

Window movement commands like ctrl w J (and ctrl w [HJKL]) also resizes windows. This can be useful when you want to leave the vertical split as is and just reset horizontal split to be equal.
